# hammer js dragstart not firing

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I have this super simple hammer.js example which works with the 'tap' event but not with 'dragstart'. I cant seem to figure out why.

```
<div id="test_el" draggable="true">HIT ME</div>
```

-

```
var element = document.getElementById('test_el');
var hammertime = Hammer(element).on("dragstart", function(event) {
    alert('hello!');
});
```

if the event is changed to tap, it works. But hammer lists dragstart as an event here.
https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started#gesture-events

Any ideas why this would not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using hammerjs v2 (the new one) drag support has been dropped.

The available events are the following:

```
Pan
Pinch
Press
Rotate
Swipe
Tap
```

and the new documentation is here: http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/